# How to generate random numbers in range from INPUT?

Tags: python, random

This is a question close to some others I have found but they don't help me so I'm asking specifically for me and my purpose this time.

I'm coding for a bot that is supposed to ask the user for max and min in a range, then generating ten random numbers within that range. When validating I'm told both `random` and `i` are unused variables. I don't really get why. I believed `random.randint` was supposed to be a built-in function and as far as `i` is concerned I really don't know what to believe. This is what I've got so far.

```
def RandomNumbers():
    """
    Asking the user for a min and max, then printing ten random numbers between min and max.
    """
    print("Give me two numbers, a min and a max")
    a = input("Select min. ")
    b = input("Select max. ")


    for i in range(10):
        number = random.randint(a, b)
    print(str(number)+ str(","), end="")
```

I'll be very happy for every piece of advice I can get to complete my task. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "validating?" `i` isn't being used, but that's OK. When you use a for-loop just for repetition, and you don't need the looping variable, convention is to make it `_`. The only problem I see with your code is that the last `print` statement should be inside the for-loop

Comment: If you're running Python 3 use `a = int(input("Select min. "))`, if you're on Python 2 use `a = int(raw_input("Select min. "))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of points worth mentioning with your original function:

- the `random` module is not built-in, you have to explicitly import it.
- `input` always returns strings, so you have to convert them to integers, before passing them to `random.randint`
- `i` is indeed not use within your for loop. You may as well replace it with `_` (reinforcing the fact, that you loop because of side-effects, e.g. printing and not the variable itself).
- More of a stylistic side-note regarding function names: PEP8 (Python style guide) encourages the use of lowercase in combination with underscore to separate words and not camel case (`random_number`vs `RandomNumber`)

Here's a working example:

```
import random 

def random_numbers():
    """
    Asking the user for a min and max, then printing ten random numbers between min and max.
    """
    print("Give me two numbers, a min and a max")
    a = int(input("Select min. "))
    b = int(input("Select max. "))

    numbers = [random.randint(a, b) for i in range(10)]
    print(','.join(str(n) for n in numbers))

random_numbers()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your full example. What does the last "random_numbers()" do? It seems like an elif which should be within my main which makes my functions work.

Comment: Also, does "import random" have to stand before "def random_numbers():"? I have multiple functions in a row so havng import random before my def would mean it is the last line of my function before it.

Comment: The last line is merely the effective call to `random_numbers` (you can safely remove it). Best practices suggest to put the import statements at the top of the file. But you may as well put them inside your function (using the same indentation, of course).

Answer (score 6):

No. `random.randint` is not a builtin function. You'll have to *import* the `random` module to use the function.

On another note, `i` was evidently not used in the loop, so you'll conventionally use the underscore `_` in place of `i`

```
import random


numbers = []
for _ in range(10):
    numbers.append(random.randint(a, b))
```

You'll also notice I have used a list to store all the values from each iteration. In that way, you don't throw away the values from previous iterations.

In case you're not already familiar with lists, you can check out the docs:

[Data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures)

*Lists:*

> The items of a list are arbitrary Python objects. Lists are formed by
>   placing a comma-separated list of expressions in square brackets

---

On a final note, to print the items from your list, you can use the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method, but not after the items in your list have been converted from integers to strings:

```
output = ', '.join([str(num) for num in numbers])
print(output)
```

Comment: Did you mean `numbers.append(..)` ?

Comment: @Cajuu' Thanks for that

Comment: Note that there is a probable indentation mistake on the last line which means that he throws away the numbers because he only wants to print them once.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand why "i" isn't used in the loop. I thought "i" WAS the range of numbers, defined within the last two brackets? for _ in range(10): (hence, in this case "1" to "10"). Thank you for explaining the use of underscore, never heard of that before:).

Comment: Also I think I forgot I have to import random, it came back to me now that you mentioned it:).

Comment: You're not using `i` for anything in the loop. The editor spots that and suggests you could use the standard placeholder `_` instead. If you did `random.randint(a, b) * i`, you won't see that warning

Answer (score 0):

Easy)

```
import random
from random import randrange

print("Give me two numbers, a min and a max")
a = int(input("Select min. "))
b = int(input("Select max. "))
c = 0
while c < 10:
    print(randrange(a, b))
    c += 1
```

You can put it in function:

```
def RandomNumbers():
    import random
    from random import randrange
    
    print("Give me two numbers, a min and a max")
    a = int(input("Select min. "))
    b = int(input("Select max. "))
    c = 0
    while c < 10:
        print(randrange(a, b))
        c += 1
```